# can it be done in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe having a column name say "c " which looks something like this.

```
df.c  = -2 , -3.66,  -7, 1 ,-3,  5,  -4.66 ,-2,  9, -1,  -7, -5.7, 3 , -5
```

without changing the order of the rows I want to find the max drop from the peak  value until the new peak is achieved

for example, to get 5 the sum of the drop is  (-4.66) +(-2) i.e -6.66    Until new peak is achieved i.e., in this case, is 9, and the drop to get 9 is

-1 + -7 + -5.7 + -5 = -18.7   as you can see i  have not considered 3 in this addition because it's positive.

So the answer that I would look for is -18.7

Comment: Can you include what you have tried so far?

Also a more detailed description of what you consider _max drop_ would be helpful, it's a bit confusing. Why is 3 in the last case not considered a new peak? Is it because it is not higher than the last peak?

Comment: the reason why 3 has not been considered as a new peak because it's less than 9. So generally we take the higher value as a peak value.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: A peak usually has a prominence https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: https://pythonawesome.com/overview-of-the-peaks-dectection-algorithms-available-in-python/

Comment: you could also use ptp https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html on parts of your array

Answer (score 1):

You can get the maximum drop simply by traversing the series:

```py
def FindMaxDrop(s):
    peak = -2147483648
    drop = 0
    ans = 0
    for num in s:
        if num > peak:
            ans = min(ans, drop)
            drop = 0
            peak = num
        if num < 0:
            drop = drop + num
    ans = min(ans, drop)
    return ans

FindMaxDrop(df.c)
```